# TextOverflow in Column using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `Text` widget inside `Column` which is inside `Padding`. And this `Padding` is children of `Row` which is the child of another `Padding`.

So the structure would be: `Container > Padding > Row > Padding > Column > Text`.

I tried to handle text overflow, but all of the overflow do not work. I tried to put the Container inside Expanded widget, but the view totally gone instead.

Here is my code :

```
Container(
      decoration: constHomeBoxDecorationStyle,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 8.0,
          horizontal: 16.0,
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            SvgPicture.asset(
              "assets/images/avatar.svg",
              width: 48.0,
              height: 48.0,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    name,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 32.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    name,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                    maxLines: 1,
                    softWrap: false,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 24.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

In the same page, I tried to build another Text Widget to test the overflow.

The structure is like this: `SingleChildScrollView > Column > Padding > Column > Text`.

This one works perfectly fine (with same Text widget code from above.

Any idea why the first one does not work?

Edit: Add screenshot and output (`A RenderFlex overflowed by 301 pixels on the right.`)
Exception :

```
The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#ece9d relayoutBoundary=up18 OVERFLOWING
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 301 pixels on the right.
The relevant error-causing widget was:
Row
lib
like a ListView.
The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#ece9d relayoutBoundary=up18 OVERFLOWING:
  creator: Row ← Padding ← DecoratedBox ← Container ← Column ← Padding ← Column ← Padding ←
    _SingleChildViewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#603bc] ← Semantics ← _PointerListener ← ⋯
  parentData: offset=Offset(16.0, 8.0) (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=296.7, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
  size: Size(296.7, 72.0)
  direction: horizontal
  mainAxisAlignment: start
  mainAxisSize: max
  crossAxisAlignment: center
  textDirection: ltr
  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

[image]

Edit 2: The Answer (based on Piyush Dubey's answer)

```
Container(
      decoration: constHomeBoxDecorationStyle,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8.0),
      child: ListTile(
        leading: SvgPicture.asset(
          "assets/images/avatar.svg",
          width: 48.0,
          height: 48.0,
        ),
        title: Text(
          name,
          maxLines: 1,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 28.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
          ),
        ),
        subtitle: Text(
          password,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 20.0,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Actually Text widget wrap themselves as the biggest parent, In the first case the Row widget has the max width/ Flutter assume that row has max width but row has limitation of context which makes it to overflow

Comment: So do you have any workaround with that? Expanded and Flexible do not work too

Comment: Can you post your end output in that case we can help with the accurate widget tree

Comment: done sir, output and the screenshot added

Comment: use ListTile Widget instead. It will be much efficient and easy for you to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ListTile widget to achieve that,

```
         ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.add),
            title: Text('GFG title',textScaleFactor: 1.5,),
            trailing: Icon(Icons.done),
            subtitle: Text('This is subtitle'),
            selected: true,
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                txt='List Tile pressed';
              });
            },
          ),
```

Comment: Thanks for the help sir, i tried this code (of course change it a bit) and it works

Comment: Great. Keep going

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `Expanded` widget as the parent of the `Padding` widget in the `Row` widget as shown below:

```
Container(
  decoration: constHomeBoxDecorationStyle,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric( // <----- REMOVED PADDING WIDGET AS CONTAINER ALREADY HAS PADDING PROPERTY
      vertical: 8.0,
      horizontal: 16.0,
    ),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        SvgPicture.asset(
          "assets/images/avatar.svg",
          width: 48.0,
          height: 48.0,
        ),
        Expanded(child: Padding( // <---------- HERE
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text(
                name,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 32.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                name,
                overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                maxLines: 1,
                softWrap: false,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 24.0,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),),
      ],
    ),
);
```

Also, there is no need to create `Padding` widget as the child of your `Container` widget as `Container` already has `padding` property.

Comment: i havent tried it yet but thank you for helping

Comment: No problem. Just try it & let me know if you are stuck. I will help you.